# Event not being fired in C# code

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a form in my VB project which has a button. The button ,on click  executes the function as shown below

```
Private Sub FrmAddMaterial_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Enter
        If LstMaterials.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            UpdateMaterialScreen(Me, LstMaterials.SelectedIndex, ErrorFlag)
        Else
            UpdateMaterialScreen(Me, 0, ErrorFlag)
        End If
    End Sub
```

I converted this whole code to C#, have binded the button to the same event as shown below.

```
 Private Sub ButNewEditSoftMaterials_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButNewEditSoftMaterials.Click
        MaterialFrm = New FrmAddMaterial
        MaterialFrm.Show()
    End Sub
```

The `FrmAddMaterial` is a form which is being loaded and has an event as shown below.

```
 private void FrmAddMaterial_Enter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LstMaterials.SelectedIndex > -1) {
                ModSoftOutput.UpdateMaterialScreen(this, LstMaterials.SelectedIndex,ref ErrorFlag);
            } else {
                ModSoftOutput.UpdateMaterialScreen(this, 0,ref ErrorFlag);
            }
        }
```

The code `FrmAddMaterial_Enter` is not being fired in `C#` but it is being fired in `VB`.I have checked the `FrmAddMaterial` property and can see the `Enter` event binded . 
What could be the problem that is not letting my `FrmAddMaterial_Enter` to fire in C# ?

Comment: I think you need to attach your listener to the Click event not the Enter event. The Enter Event is triggered when the control is entered not clicked.

Comment: Those 2 pieces of code are identical so the issue must be with attaching the handlers. Can you post that code. Also can you clarify about what your desired behaviour is with regard to entering the form vs clicking the button

Comment: You should use Click event. Enter event is fired when control is entered. Read following documentation for Enter event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That code is also not fired in VB.NET when a button is clicked. Also, FrmAddMaterial_Enter is not even triggered when a button is clicked. You are using the wrong event.

Answer (score 0):

In C# it is the `Click Event` that triggers the Click, so you have to bind your Method/Listener to that event.

> MSDN States: Occurs when the button is clicked: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx

While the `Enter Event` occurs when the control is entered, for example when you switch with Tab

> MSDN Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx

Try reassigning your Listener to the `Click Event`and it should work or at least get triggered when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN documentation of the enter Event:

> The Enter and Leave events are suppressed by the Form class. The equivalent events in the Form class are the Activated and Deactivate events.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

So they will not work with a form but only with a control.